# Create a base driver class and inherit webdriver

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

In Python/Selenium, I am trying to create a browser class mainly so I can create custom functions like click or type, etc and easily call these by typing something simple such as `browser.click(element)` or `browser.type_text(element, text)`.

I think I am sort of on the right track but I cannot get the inheritance to work. For example, when I create a browser instance with `browser = Browser()` and try to use the normal functions of webdriver like `browser.get(webpage)`, I get an error stating that there is no GET function. Am I on the right track here? Is there a better way?

```
class Browser(webdriver.Chrome):
    def __init__():
        super(self).init()
        self.browser = webdriver.Chrome()

    def click(element):
        WebDriverWait(self, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable(element)).click()

browser = Browser()
element = (By.ID, elements['remember'])
browser.click(element)
```

**Update:**
So it looks like I was able to figure out what I was originally intending to do.

I wanted to create a webdriver using a class and basically extend that library to include some custom functions. I'll explain.

```
class Browser(webdriver.Chrome):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

    def click(self, element):
        WebDriverWait(self, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable(element)).click()

    def type(self, element, text):
        for i in text:
            WebDriverWait(browser, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located(element)).send_keys(i)
            time.sleep(random.uniform(0.05,0.25))
```

So basically here I just added a custom click and type function to make it more convenient to have the webdriver wait for an element and click or type, etc.

```
browser = Browser()
browser.click(element)
browser.type(element, text)
```

Comment: You are mixing `WebDriver` and `WebElement` functionality. It's a good idea to have a class to handle the actions, but it I don't think it should inherit from anything, maybe `WebElement` if you really want to do this. But it defiantly shouldn't inherit from `WebDriver`.

Answer (score 0):

As @Guy has mentioned, your confusing the functionality of the `WebDriver` class and the `WebElement` class. The `WebDriver` class indeed has methods like `get` for URL navigation, but the `WebElement` class has methods like `click`, and so on. Rather than using your current approach, I recommend a design pattern that's popularly with Selenium: the [Page Object Model design pattern](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/page-objects.html).

Following this design pattern will allow you to easily call much simpler method names. For example, taken straight from the linked page:

```
from element import BasePageElement
from locators import MainPageLocators

class SearchTextElement(BasePageElement):
    """This class gets the search text from the specified locator"""

    #The locator for search box where search string is entered
    locator = 'q'


class BasePage(object):
    """Base class to initialize the base page that will be called from all pages"""

    def __init__(self, driver):
        self.driver = driver


class MainPage(BasePage):
    """Home page action methods come here. I.e. Python.org"""

    #Declares a variable that will contain the retrieved text
    search_text_element = SearchTextElement()

    def is_title_matches(self):
        """Verifies that the hardcoded text "Python" appears in page title"""
        return "Python" in self.driver.title

    def click_go_button(self):
        """Triggers the search"""
        element = self.driver.find_element(*MainPageLocators.GO_BUTTON)
        element.click()


class SearchResultsPage(BasePage):
    """Search results page action methods come here"""

    def is_results_found(self):
        # Probably should search for this text in the specific page
        # element, but as for now it works fine
        return "No results found." not in self.driver.page_source
```

This will allow you to make simply-named method calls:

```
MainPage.click_go_button()
```

Comment: I added additional information under the update section of my original post. Let me know if that makes sense of what I was trying to do. I see you mentioned using the page object model approach. I'm not sure I need something too complicated, but this script does interact with a login, dashboard, search and a couple other pages. I basically use the same driver and navigate around doing what I need to do on all the pages. I do have multiple processes of these going at the same time. Would you recommend me going with the POM route or does my Browser class suffice?

Comment: @FunkyEssence Over-engineering can definitely be a problem, and can lead to an over-complicated solution. Depending on what you're using this script for, using one or multiple drivers is up to you. In regards to using POM vs. your Browser class, if you have many different elements that you want to interact with on any given page, then the POM is definitely the way to go, as it helps clarify the relationship between elements and their page. However, if you're only interested in a couple of the elements on the page, spelling out each element and passing it to your Browser class will be fine

Comment: @FunkyEssence PS, your `Browser` class on its own is fine, as it deals with the `WebDriver`. It has nothing to do with POM, which deals with the `WebElement` objects. You could still use POM, which would then use your `Browser` object rather than straight-up using a `WebDriver` object